# Minimum number of ways of dividing an $M\times N$ chocolate bar into square pieces of unit side length

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find minimum number of ways of dividing an $M\times N$ chocolate bar into square pieces of unit side length. Note that at a time only one piece can be cut, unlike piling a stack and cutting through. The cuts can only be made horizontally or vertically.

I have tried using symmetry but to no use. Is there is a definite answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note:  each break adds exactly one to the number of connected components.  Thus, no matter what you do, it will always take $MN-1$ breaks.

Comment: What about a $2 \times 2$-sized bar? We can cut this into unit pieces with just $2$ cuts, not $3$. I must be missing something here.

Comment: @AOrtiz Not without stacking them? And you need $3$ cuts ($2 \times 2 -1$).

Comment: @Lovsovs Okay, I can see how my second cut would be a cut on two stacked pieces. Thanks.

Comment: @lulu I was thinking about the minimum amount of cuts needed when stacking *is* allowed, but it doesn't seem to be trivial. Any thoughts on how to approach that case?

Comment: @Lovsovs  Nothing leaps to mind...but I agree it's an interesting question.