# Minimum number of cuts to separate all pieces of an $m\times n$ chocolate bar when stacking is allowed

Tags: combinatorics, symmetry, discrete-optimization

Inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1896374/259085), where stacking the cut off pieces wasn't allowed.

We want a function $F(m,n)=k$ for $\{m,n,k\}\in\mathbb{N}$ that gives the number of cuts or foldings $k$ required to transform the $m\times n$ chocolate bar into $mn$ square, separate pieces.

For instance, for $2\times 2$, you could fold the bar over its middle two times to get a tower $4$ (separated) pieces high. So $F(2,2)=2$. In general, $F(2^n,2^n)=2n$.

However, for more asymmetrical cases, I'm unable to make much progress. I guess one would need to construct an optimal algorithm and take the calculations from there, so any help in constructing that would also be much appreciated!

Comment: This would seem to be related to multiplication through repeated doubling

Comment: What is a "folding" here? Does cutting your chocolate down the middle and then stacking the two pieces on each other count as one or two operations?

Comment: @HenningMakholm That counts as one fold (even though the cut doesn't have to be down the middle), so one operation.

Comment: @Lovsovs: Is that a different metric than just counting cuts and letting stacking be a free action, then?

Comment: @HenningMakholm No, that would be the same :)

Comment: Note that a three-dimensional version of this question was asked in the Puzzling stack exchange: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/36262/get-together-to-get-her

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple optimal algorithm would be

> Imagine extending the initial chocolate bar to the right and top as necessary to make each dimension a power of $2$ and then use the obvious cut-in-halves algorithm on the extended bar. In each of the cuts you're guaranteed that there will be *some* real chocolate to cut through, namely the part that contains the original bottom-left corner.

This gives $F(n,m) = \lceil\log_2 n\rceil + \lceil \log_2 m\rceil$.

We can see that it is impossible to get by with fewer steps by long induction on $n+m$. No matter how you make the initial cut, the larger of the pieces that are left will have a $\lceil\log_2 n\rceil + \lceil \log_2 m\rceil$ that has decreased by at most $1$ -- and so by induction, getting *that piece* down to individual squares is going to take at least $\lceil\log_2 n\rceil + \lceil \log_2 m\rceil - 1$ additional cuts, no matter which way you choose to stack parts of the *smaller* piece into those additional cuts.

We see that having freedom to turn pieces by $90^\circ$ before stacking will never save cuts, nor will having the ability to un-stack pieces after cutting.

Comment: I don't quite see how you get from your updated algorithm description to the formula, since you have now extended the whole plate? Could you elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: @Lovsovs: I'm extending the plate from $n\times m$ to $2^{\lceil \log_2 n\rceil}\times 2^{\lceil \log_2 m\rceil}$ and then applying the formula in your question to the extended plate.

Comment: Uah, that is clever!